# Selenium XPATH I am trying to locate an element from column 2 from a HTML table where text value is in column 1

Tags: python-2.7, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I have a HTML table with an input value "AREACODE" in column 1 and column 2 has a select element (a drop down field).  I am trying to locate the select element which is in the same row as the input value "AREACODE"
I can locate the Input element which has the value "AREACODE"
I am not sure how to go to the next column td in the same row to get to the Select element.

My XPATH is:

```
//table[@id="data_configuration_edit_data_object_tab_details_tb_fields"]/tbody//tr//td//div//input[@value="AREACODE"]/following-sibling/td/div/select
```

I have also tried:

```
//table[@id="data_configuration_edit_data_object_tab_details_tb_fields"]/tbody//tr//td//div//input[@value="AREACODE"]/following-sibling::td/div/select
```

The HTML snippet is:

```
    <table id="data_configuration_edit_data_object_tab_details_tb_fields" class="GFNQNVHJE border" cellspacing="0" __gwtcellbasedwidgetimpldispatchingfocus="true" __gwtcellbasedwidgetimpldispatchingblur="true">
    <thead aria-hidden="false">
        <colgroup>
            <tbody style="">
                <tr class="GFNQNVHCD GFNQNVHJD" __gwt_subrow="0" __gwt_row="0">
                    <td class="GFNQNVHBD GFNQNVHDD GFNQNVHED GFNQNVHKD">
                        <td class="GFNQNVHBD GFNQNVHDD GFNQNVHKD">
                            <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-319" style="outline-style:none;">
                                <input id="" type="text" style="color: black;" value="AREACODE"/>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="GFNQNVHBD GFNQNVHDD GFNQNVHKD">
                            <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-320" style="outline-style:none;">
                                <select tabindex="-1">
                                    <option value="Integer">Integer</option>
                                    <option selected="selected" value="Text string">Text string</option>
                                    <option value="Date/time">Date/time</option>
                                    <option value="Floating point">Floating point</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="GFNQNVHBD GFNQNVHDD GFNQNVHOD GFNQNVHKD">
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="GFNQNVHCE" __gwt_subrow="0" __gwt_row="1">
                            <tr class="GFNQNVHCD" __gwt_subrow="0" __gwt_row="2">
                            </tbody>
                            <tbody style="display: none;">
                                <tfoot style="display: none;" aria-hidden="true"/>
</table>
```

To get the input element where Value = "AREACODE" the XPATH is:

```
//table[@id="data_configuration_edit_data_object_tab_details_tb_fields"]/tbody//tr//td//div//input[@value="AREACODE"]
```

Now how do i go to the next column where the select element is?

What is the correct XPATH please?
Thanks, Riaz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this xpath

```
"//table[@id='data_configuration_edit_data_object_tab_details_tb_fields']//td/div/input[@value='AREACODE']/../../following-sibling::td[1]/div/select"
```

Answer (score 1):

You should try using below `xpath` :-

```
.//table[@id='data_configuration_edit_data_object_tab_details_tb_fields']//tr[descendant::input[@value='AREACODE']]//select
```

Or using [`following-sibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes/following-sibling) Axes as :-

```
.//table[@id='data_configuration_edit_data_object_tab_details_tb_fields']//tr//td[div/input[@value='AREACODE']]/following-sibling::td//select
```